# C++ FTP writing to file is not working

Tags: c++, file, upload, ftp

I wrote this code that is **SUPPOSED** to write to a file on an ftp server, but it doesn't work. The file stays 0 bytes. There are also no errors. Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int error=0;
    char buffer[256];
    char *text="Hello world.";
    HINTERNET hOpen=InternetOpen("",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE);
    InternetGetLastResponseInfo((LPDWORD)error,(LPSTR)buffer,(LPDWORD)256);
    printf("hOpen:%d:%s\n",error,buffer);
    HINTERNET hConnect=InternetConnect(hOpen,"diabloip.host22.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,"MY_USER_NAME","MY_PASSWORD",INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0);
    InternetGetLastResponseInfo((LPDWORD)error,(LPSTR)buffer,(LPDWORD)256);
    printf("hConnect:%d:%s\n",error,buffer);
    HINTERNET hFile=FtpOpenFile(hConnect,"diabloip.host22.com/public_html/log.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII,0);
    InternetGetLastResponseInfo((LPDWORD)error,(LPSTR)buffer,(LPDWORD)256);
    printf("hFile:%d:%s\n",error,buffer);
    InternetWriteFile(hFile,text,strlen(text),NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know, when you pass the proper arguments to the functions you don't need all that casting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is passing `NULL` as the last parameter to `InternetWriteFile`.  It is not an optional parameter and if you had error checking for that call as the rest you'd see `GetLastError` returns 87, or `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

This works correctly and cleans up some of the other issues with incorrect parameters and the excessive casting that masks the issues.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

void PrintStatus(const char* title)
{
    DWORD error = 0;
    DWORD sz = 256;
    char buffer[256];
    InternetGetLastResponseInfo(&error, buffer, &sz);
    printf("%s:%u:%s\n", title, error, buffer);
}

int main()
{
    const char *text = "Hello world.";
    HINTERNET hOpen = InternetOpen("", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE);
    PrintStatus("hOpen");
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hOpen, "localhost", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "test", "test", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
    PrintStatus("hConnect");
    HINTERNET hFile = FtpOpenFile(hConnect, "log.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0);
    PrintStatus("hFile");
    DWORD wb = 0;
    BOOL Success = InternetWriteFile(hFile, text, strlen(text), &wb);
    if(!Success)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("InternetWriteFile - Error = %u\n", err);
    }
    PrintStatus("InternetWriteFile");
    InternetCloseHandle(hOpen);
    return 0;
}
```